# How to optimize convertions in encrypted SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have an encrypted database table and i want to select data from that for some calculations. A lot of conversions are needed for this and encrypt again to update the table. how can i optimize my query.
Sample query

```
SELECT @Total=CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey([Amount1])) AS numeric(12, 2))+
CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey([Amount2])) AS numeric(12, 2))*@Percent FROM Table1

UPDATE Table1
SET [Total]= EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('KEY_67832'), CONVERT(varchar,@Total))
```

Comment: You are performing the `DecryptByKey()` twice. Why not do it once and use the result twice?

Comment: ohh sorry, Actually it was another field

Comment: Hmm in that case my answer probably won't help

Comment: thanks for answering

Comment: if we use temp tables instead of convertions. Is it increase efficiency?

Comment: It can do if it saves work, but in this case I don't think it will.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey([Amount1])) AS numeric(12, 2)) Amount1,
       PrimaryKey -- not sure if you need this, but I added it in case...
INTO   TempTable
FROM   Table1

SELECT @Total=Amount1 + Amount1 * @Percent FROM TempTable

-- this bit unchanged (so far)
UPDATE Table1
SET [Total]= EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('KEY_67832'), CONVERT(varchar,@Total))
```

Comment: Is there anything to avoid 2 conversions. Can we convert directly to numeric

Comment: There's a post here about converting from VARBINARY to DECIMAL: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=186457